# C# Sign pdf using itext with External service

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I need to sign pdf with external web service. But there is an error on signed pdf like Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed.

[image: HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //StreamSign();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"E:\pdf-exampleSign\example.pdf");
        //MemoryStream os = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(@"E:\pdf-exampleSign\example_tmp.pdf");

        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "Signature");
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 20000);

        byte[] hash = SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        var hex = builder.ToString();

        //HERE IS THE SERVER SIDE BASE64 STRING I GOT
        string ServerSideSignedBytes = "MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgE.....";
        byte[] signbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ServerSideSignedBytes);

        X509Certificate2 certt = new X509Certificate2(signbytes);
        var cert = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(certt.GetRawCertData());
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[1];
        chain[0] = cert;

        using (PdfReader prereader = new PdfReader(@"E:\pdf-exampleSign\example_tmp.pdf"))
        {
            using (FileStream preos = File.OpenWrite(@"E:\pdf-exampleSign\example_signed.pdf"))
            {
                IExternalSignatureContainer externallast = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signbytes, chain);
                MakeSignature.SignDeferred(prereader, "Signature", preos, externallast);
            }
        }
    }
public class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    protected byte[] sig;
    protected Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain;
    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain)
    {
        this.sig = sig;
        this.chain = chain;
    }
    public byte[] Sign(Stream s)
    {
        return sig;
    }
    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) { }
}
```

Comment: *`//HERE IS THE SERVER SIDE BASE64 STRING I GOT`* - Each time you start your code anew, you get a different `hash` to sign. Thus, you cannot simply use some signature bytes you retrieved for a different run, let alone for some different data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read your answers through the digital sign questions and i got the answers i needed. Thank you again.